# How can i find which release of OSGI is supported by CQ5.5 .?

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

How can we find which release of OSGi is supported by CQ5.5 version, Is there any log file where i can find out the OSGi release in the CQ5 product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQ5.5 uses [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/) which is

> ... a community effort to implement the **[OSGi R4](http://www.osgi.org/Release4/HomePage)** Service Platform and other interesting OSGi-related technologies under the Apache license

The references to OSGI in the [javadocs at dev.day.com](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/javadoc/index.html) point to [R4 v4.2](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/overview-summary.html) specifically.  This matches the [compliance tests](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FELIX/Using+the+OSGi+Compliance+Tests) for the felix project

If you're building against the OSGI APIs in your application, then you'll need to add the following to your project pom.xml (assuming you're using maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

in CQ 5.6 we don't use the org.ogsi dependencies anymore. instead we have (amongst others)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.osgi</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency
```

also you have (again in 5.6, not sure about 5.5) a depfinder

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/depfinder
```

here you can see which package/version a certain class you need belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

> The implementation of OSGi used by CQ is Apache Felix, which implements OSGi Service Platform Release 4.

You can find out more detail about CQ's Technical Foundation at http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/exploring/concepts.html